# Convert NSString to unsigned in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

I want to convert an `NSString` to an `unsigned int`.

Why? Because I want to do parallel payment in PayPal.

Below I have given my coding in which I want to convert the `NSString` to an unsigned int.

My query is:

```
    //optional, set shippingEnabled to TRUE if you want to display shipping
    //options to the user, default: TRUE
    [PayPal getPayPalInst].shippingEnabled = TRUE;
    
    //optional, set dynamicAmountUpdateEnabled to TRUE if you want to compute
    //shipping and tax based on the user's address choice, default: FALSE
    [PayPal getPayPalInst].dynamicAmountUpdateEnabled = TRUE;
    
    //optional, choose who pays the fee, default: FEEPAYER_EACHRECEIVER
    [PayPal getPayPalInst].feePayer = FEEPAYER_EACHRECEIVER;
    
    //for a payment with multiple recipients, use a PayPalAdvancedPayment object
    PayPalAdvancedPayment *payment = [[PayPalAdvancedPayment alloc] init];
    payment.paymentCurrency = @"USD";
    
    // A payment note applied to all recipients.
    payment.memo = @"A Note applied to all recipients";
    
    //receiverPaymentDetails is a list of PPReceiverPaymentDetails objects
    payment.receiverPaymentDetails = [NSMutableArray array];
    
    NSArray *emailArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"abc@def.com",@"def@abc.com", nil];
    
    for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
        PayPalReceiverPaymentDetails *details = [[PayPalReceiverPaymentDetails alloc] init];
        
        // Customize the payment notes for one of the three recipient.
        if (i == 2) {
            details.description = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Component %d", i];
        }
        
        details.recipient = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[emailArray objectAtIndex:i-1]];
        
        unsigned order;
        
        if (i==1) {
            order = [[feeArray objectAtIndex:0] unsignedIntValue];
        }
        if (i==2) {
             order = [[amountArray objectAtIndex:0] unsignedIntValue];
        }
        
        //subtotal of all items for this recipient, without tax and shipping
        details.subTotal = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithMantissa:order exponent:-4 isNegative:FALSE];
        
        //invoiceData is a PayPalInvoiceData object which contains tax, shipping, and a list of PayPalInvoiceItem objects
        details.invoiceData = [[PayPalInvoiceData alloc] init];
        
        //invoiceItems is a list of PayPalInvoiceItem objects
        //NOTE: sum of totalPrice for all items must equal details.subTotal
        //NOTE: example only shows a single item, but you can have more than one
        details.invoiceData.invoiceItems = [NSMutableArray array];
        PayPalInvoiceItem *item = [[PayPalInvoiceItem alloc] init];
        item.totalPrice = details.subTotal;
        [details.invoiceData.invoiceItems addObject:item];
        
        [payment.receiverPaymentDetails addObject:details];
    }
    
    [[PayPal getPayPalInst] advancedCheckoutWithPayment:payment];
```

Can anybody tell me how to do this conversion?

Comment: And your question is? Also, I think you mean `unsigned int` instead of `unsigned`

Comment: @TomvanderWoerdt, I think int is optional in Objective-c, if you just write unsigned its mean unsigned int.

Comment: @Siddiqui It's optional in C, yes. Doesn't make it a good habit.

Comment: can anybody give a detail explanation about my query, how to do

Comment: Did any of the provided answers help you or actually answer your question?

Comment: To request support for reading unsigned values from NSString, please visit http://bugreport.apple.com and file a dupe of radar://2264733 against component `Foundation | X`.

Answer (score 3):

In my case I had to implement something like this (adapt to your needs):

```
NSString *myStringObject = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u", someObject.hash];
NSUInteger hashValue = (NSUInteger)myStringObject.longLongValue;
```

I originally used `myStringObject.intValue`, as suggested below, but then my integers were getting "clipped" because they were too big when assumed signed (but not too big unsigned due to the extra bit). Using `myStringObject.longLongValue` fixed the problem for me.

I should note that my strings were originally created using NSUIntegers (unsigned ints) so I didn't have to worry about parsing an integer that was too big.

Comment: Any reason you didn't simply use `longLongValue`?

Comment: That's probably the better method, isn't it? I've adjusted my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your array has a string in it:

```
unsigned int order = (unsigned int)[[feeArray objectAtIndex:0] intValue];
```

There really is no NSString method to convert directly to unsigned int values.  However if you can guarantee that none of your values are signed ints, then the above should work for you.

Comment: i am using this query in paypal for getting through parallel payment

Comment: The only thing at this point if it doesnt work for you that I can think of off the top of my head, is that somehow you dont have NSString objects in your array.  How are you generating your feeArray and amountArray?

Answer (score 1):

There is no conversion to *unsigned* integer, however there is a conversion to *signed* integer (`NSInteger`):

```
NSInteger order = [[freeArray objectAtIndex:0] integerValue];
NSLog(@"order=%ld", order);
```

or `int`:

```
int order = [[freeArray objectAtIndex:0] intValue];
NSLog(@"order=%d", order);
```